# Is it possible to install Xposed for Oreo 8.0 without breaking the Safetynet Check?

Tags: rooting, stock-android, android-versions, xposed-framework, systemless-root

From my research, the two seem to be mutually exclusive: Not passing the Safetynet check will break certain apps like G Pay and Snapchat, but installing Xposed for 8.0 doesn't seem possible without breaking the check.

Can anyone confirm or deny this? If possible, how?

Comment: Although I have been out of the realm of rooting personally for some time, I work with users on it all the time... To my knowledge, installing breaks SafetyNet API checks in all cases.

Comment: That was already the case in the past. For example, Magisk describes it passes SafetyNet check – unless you install Xposed (even systemless), which then will break it. I'd assume nothing has changed in this regard.

Comment: @Izzy It isn't the case for all versions. I currently run Android Marshmallow on my Galaxy S5, with pre-November-2016 patches. I have Root and Xposed installed and actively running, and my device passes all SafetyNet checks and will run Pokemon Go as of 2018. Other than the specific pre-patch ROM versions, you're correct that there is no combination to allow Xposed and also pass SafetyNet.

Comment: @StephenSchrauger Good to read there are exceptions! And luckily, for me SafetyNet is not a must. I use nothing that would complain :)